# programmatically adding a module to a gnosis safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, foundry, forge

I am developing a module for a pre-existing safe. The safe is a recipient of a vesting contract. The module claims the eligible tokens, claims tokens from a staking contract and then re-stakes all the tokens in the safe.

I am using foundry for my tests, so I need to install the module in solidity as part of my test setup. I have searched stack exchange and GitHub for any examples of modules being installed into a live safe with no luck. Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The [ModuleManager.sol](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/ModuleManager.sol) contract handles the admin actions regarding modules, like enable/disable modules, executing transactions via a module, checking if a module is enabled, etc.

These are the steps you need to follow to enable a module:

1. Call the [enableModule](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/ModuleManager.sol#L32) function. It has the modifier `authorized` so you need to call it by executing a transaction from your Safe.
2. Optionally you can check if the module is already enabled by calling [isModuleEnabled](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/ModuleManager.sol#L105) function.
3. The module is ready to call the [execTransactionFromModule](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/ModuleManager.sol#L61) function. Because now the module is enabled, [this condition](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/base/ModuleManager.sol#L68) will pass.